# How can I add a button to the WPF caption bar while using custom window chrome?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm attempting to create a simple button template in which the button normally looks like a single horizontal line, but when moused over, the button will display a "rectangle" color fill behind it.  This is the code I have, but I can't seem to get the triggers to fire.

```
<Window x:Class="TestStylingWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="36" GlassFrameThickness="0 0 0 1" ResizeBorderThickness="5" />
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="36" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Height="36" Width="36" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Grid.Row="0">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_ButtonBackgroundRectangle" Fill="LightGray" Width="36" Height="36" Opacity="0" />
                        <Path x:Name="PART_ButtonPath" Data="M10,26 L26,26" Stroke="DarkGray" StrokeThickness="1.5" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger SourceName="PART_ButtonBackgroundRectangle" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_ButtonBackgroundRectangle" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Does anyone know why my trigger won't work, or perhaps a better way to do this? I'm sort of new to WPF and would like to refactor this out (so as to use it in many buttons), but am unsure how.

**Update:** Ok, so I guess it appears to be because the button is within the caption bar of the window.  Is there a good way around this?  Maybe a way to set click/hover priority to the button?

Comment: Copied into an empty wpf project your code works just fine. So your problem lies somewhere else...

Comment: Updated my answer and code with some new info.

Comment: @ChrisCovert Please check your code in a clean solution before saying there's something wrong with it. Your updated code also doesn't seem to have any problems.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a clean solution, but apparently that was up at the top. I guess the lack of window borders should have tipped me off.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to set Hittest visible of your button, such as:

```
shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"
```

Comment: @ChrisCovert But how? In a 4.5.2 project, If I add a reference to `xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Windows.Shell"` and try to set the property `shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"` on my buttons, I get the error *"The name "WindowChrome" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/shell""*

Comment: @Okuma.Scott you can use a resource dictionary to add this to a style.

Comment: NOTE : there's no need to add shell just use ` WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"` and it works fine :)

Comment: But this will disable moving the window on titleBar drag, also in windows 11 it will disable window snapping popup. Are there any solution?