# WPF Custom Chrome Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, window, visual-c#-express-2010

i have been trying to make something along the lines of this...[image]

I have looked and looked and only found this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/131515/WPF-Custom-Chrome-Library).
I am having trouble integrating this into my application. I just started WPF today, so i am learning.  I have downloded the window.Shell dLL. What else do i need? Thanks!

Comment: what is it that you do not get in the linked article?

Comment: What DLL's do i need? Do i have all of them? i just have the Shell DLL. How do i do it? All i see is some Xaml, it is confusing.

Comment: Sorry if i do not get all of it...ha it is very new to me.

Comment: Well, @Mic , i know what you mean. I have the regular window thing figured out. I have started customizing my own window. It has worked out very well, with shadows, and borders. But when i was looking for re sizing, and those custom close buttons, i saw this and wanted to implement it into my application.

Comment: thanks @Mic i have also looked at this article...it really does not help me either. http://wpfwindow.codeplex.com/

Comment: in the link you provided is all you need just download the sample Source go into `CustomChromeLibrary` and check it out and don't forget  Themes->Generic.xaml ;) maybe you should give us further information's about what you were able to produce so far

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are looking for a step-by-step guide on how to add this to your application I can give it a try; I just happened to need a bit of a brush-up for a small app, I liked this and gave it a try - it took me about 45 minutes to apply. Cool stuff actually!

First: Download the **source** application and extract it to your computer.

In it you will find three subfolders. One with the sample application, one named Microsoft.Windows.Shell, one named CustomChromeLibrary. Copy the latter two to the root folder of **your** project map, **add** them to your project map (add existing project) and, from your startup project, **reference** them.

Now open the Window you want to apply CustomChromeLibrary to. You need to change the root from

```
<Window>
```

to

```
<ccl:CustomChromeWindow>
```

, this is done by using this code as the document root:

```
<ccl:CustomChromeWindow 
Title="YourWindowTitle" Height="268" Width="733" ResizeMode="CanResize" 
x:Class="YourNamespace.YourWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:shell="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/shell"
xmlns:ccl="clr-namespace:CustomChromeLibrary;assembly=CustomChromeLibrary"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace" 
>
```

Pay attention to the last three lines in the sample. These need to be updated to reference the correct libraries; the last one actually referencing to YOUR namespace.

Next you need to update the source code of your window as this is still a simple Window and you will receive an error from it.

Change this

```
public partial class YourWindow : Window
```

to this

```
public partial class YourWindow : CustomChromeLibrary.CustomChromeWindow
```

You are already half way there!

Next you just need to create the objects for your window (title bar etc.). This is wonderfully done in the **sample project No. 5**; I did really just copy it.

Take everything from

```
<shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <shell:WindowChrome
    ...
```

to here

```
    <!--min/max/close buttons-->
    <ccl:CaptionButtons/>
```

Now you can fill your Window like this

```
    <Grid> 
        The content of your Window goes here 
    </Grid>
```

And close the xaml like this

```
    </Grid>
</ccl:CustomChromeWindow>
```

Now, if you try to run this you will receive another error. There are still three files missing:

The first one you need is a Microsoft file: CaptionButtonRectToMarginConverter.cs; you will also find it in the sample. Copy it to your project and add it (add existing file).

You need to make one change to it:

```
namespace YourNamespace
{ ...
```

instead of the sample's namespace.

Finally you need the two xaml files that create the buttons: GlassButton.xaml and GlassIcon.xaml; they can be found in the "Resources" subfolder (and are referenced as resource dictionaries in the xaml). Copy the whole subfolder to your project and add the two files to your project (add existing file).

Now you should finally be able to run your project.

Let's not forget this: Lots of kudos to [gbahns](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=4540883), the author of the original article over at codeplex.com!

Comment: Very thorough, I wish I could give you 100 points for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There are quite a few implementations you can find for a custom chrome.

Another helper library I've seen to one you linked is

[MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/)

Read section 3. It can be setup with Nuget making it more easier to integrate for someone new.

Also section 3.3 3.4 3.5 talk about customising and expanding the `MetroWindow` control which gives you a custom chrome and also allows adding controls to the chrome title bar

Comment: Thanks. The only thing i am really needing is to restore the original window function, with the button style like those in the image.

Comment: By original window function if you mean (close, restore/maximise and minimise) you get that with the metro apps library as well. Just pick the sections you want and use them. Have a read through the documentation. The code-project glass theme article is also something I have tried. However had some issues with it on windows 8 and window maximise skewing chrome dimensions

Comment: The metro thing looks more complicated. I thought all i had to do for this one was add some dll's and Change the Xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Over in this stack overflow question:

[How can I add a button to the WPF caption bar while using custom window chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431112/how-can-i-add-a-button-to-the-wpf-caption-bar-while-using-custom-window-chrome)

I was asking about how to insert buttons into the title bar of my Custom Window Chrome window. The xaml example might be enough to help you get going.

Other than that, I'm not sure what you are looking for.

Edit: The button style I have in that other post is a fairly simplistic button, but you should be able to replace it with any styling that you want.